# while downloading a file using java code, the lines in file skips the newline character

Tags: java, download, filewriter

i am writing to a file using java code like this.

```
File errorfile = new File("ErrorFile.txt");
FileWriter ef = new FileWriter(errorfile, true);
BufferedWriter eb = new BufferedWriter(ef);
eb.write("the line contains error");
eb.newLine();
eb.write("the error being displayed");
eb.newLine();
eb.write("file ends");
eb.close();
ef.close();
```

this file is being saved on the server. now when i download the file using java code it skips the newline character. the code for downloading is:

```
String fname = "ErrorFile.txt";
BufferedInputStream filein = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(fname); // path of file
            if (file.exists()) {
                byte b[] = new byte[2048];
                int len = 0;
                filein = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                response.setContentType("application/force-download");
                response.setHeader("content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fname);  // downloaded file name
                response.setHeader("content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                while ((len = filein.read(b)) > 0) {
                    output.write(b, 0, len);
                    output.flush();
                }
                output.close();
                filein.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("e2: " + e1.toString());
        }
```

now when i open the downloaded file, it should look like:

```
the line contains error
the error being displayed
file ends
```

but the output is

```
the line contains error (then a box like structure) the error being displayed (then a box like structure) file ends.
```

please suggest...

Comment: That can happen if the server runs Linux/Unix and the client runs Windows.

Comment: And how is it downloaded on the other end? You do not tell

Comment: @BalusC thats correct ... my server is linux and client is windows.. is theris any solution to this??

Comment: How are you viewing the file? Notepad? Try Notepad++ it will treat \n as a line-break.

Comment: Why have you put this in your code: response.setHeader("content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary"); As far as I can tell this says you *want* the file exactly as it is on the server (with linux line breaks).

Comment: Also response.setContentType("text/plain"); might be enough to make sure the line breaks get converted to be Windows-friendly.

Comment: thanx alot @PeterCrotty i got it right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *@BalusC thats correct ... my server is linux and client is windows.. is theris any solution to this??*

Any starting developer or at least computer enthusiast should know that Linux/Unix based operating systems use `\n` as newline character and that Windows uses `\r\n` as newline characters. The `\n` fails in Windows, however the `\r\n` works fine in Linux/Unix (it must, otherwise e.g. HTTP which also mandates `\r\n` would fail in Linux/Unix as well).

[The `newLine()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29) which you're using to print the newline only prints the system's default newline which is thus `\n` at your server. However, your client, which is Windows based, expects `\r\n`.

You need to replace

```
eb.newLine();
```

by

```
eb.write("\r\n");
```

in order to get it to work across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

i used this code for my problem... and its working...

```
String fname = "ErrorFile.txt";
BufferedInputStream filein = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(fname); // path of file
        if (file.exists()) {               
            int len = 0;
            filein = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            response.setContentType("APPLICATION/DOWNLOAD");
            response.setHeader("content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fname);      // downloaded file name              
            while ((len = filein.read()) != -1) {
                output.write(len);
                output.flush();
            }
            output.close();
            filein.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        System.out.println("e2: " + e1.toString());
    }
```